# How to set delay to change buttons color

Tags: java, android

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    take = getIntent();
    levelone = take.getIntArrayExtra("level1");
    take = getIntent();
    leveltwo = take.getIntArrayExtra("level2");
    take = getIntent();
    levelthree = take.getIntArrayExtra("level3");
    colors[0] = (R.drawable.blue1);//Suppose to give integer value for the colors
    colors[1] = (R.drawable.purple1);
    colors[2] = (R.drawable.yellow1);
    colors[3] = (R.drawable.green1);
    colors1[0] = (R.drawable.blue);//Suppose to set the colors back to origin
    colors1[1] = (R.drawable.purple);
    colors1[2] = (R.drawable.yellow);
    colors1[3] = (R.drawable.green);


    purple = findViewById(R.id.purplee);   //1
    green = findViewById(R.id.greenn);//2
    yellow = findViewById(R.id.yelloww);//3
    blue = findViewById(R.id.bluee);//4

    for (int i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = findViewById(btn[i]);
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }
            buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);//purple Butttons[1]
    buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors[2]);//Yellow Buttons[2]
    buttons[3].setBackgroundResource(colors[3]);//Green Buttons[3]
    buttons[0].setBackgroundResource(colors[0]);//Blue Buttons[0]

    //  Blue Buttons[0],purple Butttons[1] ,Yellow Buttons[2],Green Buttons[3]
    //colors[0]==Blue  ,colors[1]==purple,colors[2]==Green,colors[3]==Yellow


             //Set background button color}

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               /* buttons[0].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); //Suppose to change the color to the primary color*/
                for(int i=0;i<levelone.length;i++)
                {
                    buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);

                }
            }
        }, 1000);//Set delay between changes of colors
```

I wanted to realize how to set delay to change the buttons background color like about 1 second after and then coming back to origin , I tried to do something like it but it didn't work and I have no clue on what should work so thanks for helpers!

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it crash because the Handler you've made isn't initialized with the main thread looper?

Comment: It's just don't set the delay

Comment: do you want change on every button cause you are using static value in for loop
```buttons[1].setBackgroundResource(colors[1]);```
Also try using bigger number  delay to check if it's working or not.

Comment: I am building game that sets sequences of colors , So there's suppose to be a sequence of colors until 4 or 6 or 8 , I mean it suppose to change colors in 0.5 milliseconds between the next stage of the sequence that it's actually replacing the original color I set it in the Xml to other color I set , but it doesn't set the delay so it's just painting all of the buttons .